# Jinja2 filter nested dictionary based on boolean value

Tags: jinja2

I have the following dict variable `users` in Jinja2:

```
  "users": {
    "user1": {
      "alive": true,
      "age": 22
    },
    "user2": {
      "alive": false,
      "age": 34
    }
  }
```

and I want to filter all alive users with jinja filter, but after a long search I am still not able to achieve that on such nested structure. Could anyone please help?

For now, I am just passing all users with `{{ users }}`, but I guess it should be possible to filter it with built in Jinja filters. Just cannot figure out the right sequence of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
users: {'user1': {'alive': True, 'age': 22}, 'user2': {'alive': False, 'age': 34}}
```

this j2 file does the job:

```
{% for user in users if users[user].alive %}
{{ user }}: {{ users[user] }}
{% endfor %}
```

result:

```
user1: {'alive': True, 'age': 22}
```